# Node js read/write concurrency with mongoose/mongodb

Tags: node.js, multithreading, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm developing an API for sending SMS with an Http request. I use node js and mongoose. So I have a problem like the one with multi thread application.

The fact is that when a user send a sms, I verify the number of sms he has already sent in database (using mongoose) and if the number doesn't exceed a limit his sms is sent and the number of sms he has sent is increment in the database (there is a value for the number of sms he has sent in the hour,day,week and month in the schema). But the fact is that I use a callbacks for the process of read value and increment value and many other operation in my code.

So the problem (I think) is that when user send requests very quickly the server different callbacks read the same count of the sms sent, authorize user to sent sms, increment and save the same value so that the count of sms is false.

In a multi thread application that access to a variable the solution would be to prevent other threads to read a variable before the actual thread has done all of it works.

With Node js event system and access to data in mongoDB I just don't know how to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance for the answers.

PS: I don't know the solution but it will be good if it works also with clusters that allow node js to use multi core.

Comment: You could add messages in a queue and only process the next one only after the previous one was processed.

Comment: Also, read this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cristy, I have solved the main part of my problem using [async queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html).

My application works well when I run it the default way of node js.
But there is an other problem. I intend to run my code on a server that has 4 cores so I want to use the node cluster module. But when I used this... because it runs code like 4 differents process (I used a server with 4 cores) they use differents queues and the error I mention earlier always occured, they read and write to the database without waiting for other thread to finish processing verifications + update.

So I would like to know what should I do to have an optimal and fast application.
Should I stop to use the cluster module and don't take benefit of multi core server (I don't think it is the best answer)?
Should I store it in my mongodb (maybe try to not persist the queue but store it in the memory in other to make it faster) ?
Is there a way to share the queue in the code when I use cluster?

What is my best choice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try some cache approach. 
now I meet same situation with you.
I will try to use cache to store the record_id that is in process.
When new request come, the coming process need check cache. If the record_id is in cache that means that record is using by other thread. So that thread need wait or do something else until finish. And when the process finish that will remove the record_id in cache in callback function

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I don't really know how I can do this... Can I have a code snippet?

Comment: Well, It wont reach by some code. You have to use some other tool to be the cache like redis, It will store as cache and auto recover if needed. The Nodejs Code can handle but very complexity.